# Getting blank page using Print Document?

Tags: c#, printdocument

Before this application was working perfectly , 
now i have problem with printing document , i am using drawstring to write report , but all data which is under loop not printing and other like Heading and footer printing normally. where is problem please ? my huge code like this .

```
posicaoDaLinha = margemSup + (linhaAtual * ToInt32(fonteNormal.GetHeight(e.Graphics)));
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.DarkGray, 15), margemEsq, (posicaoDaLinha + 7.5f), margemDir, (posicaoDaLinha + 7.5f));
e.Graphics.DrawString("DINHEIRO", fonteNormal, Brushes.Black, margemEsq, posicaoDaLinha, new StringFormat());
e.Graphics.DrawString(" R$" + caixa.dinheiro.ToString(), fonteNormal, Brushes.Black, margemEsq + 150, posicaoDaLinha, new StringFormat());
linhaAtual++;
```

i also tried by changing fonts but still not printing .

Comment: Have you tried writing the graphics to a bitmap/file to see if the bug lies with the graphic or the printing?

Comment: not . but all preview i tried to save as PDF ,in PDF also not showing data .

Comment: Your posicaoDaLinha in the first line - is it of type float? If so, why do you call ToInt32 in the first line?

Comment: this report almost 2 year worked perfect now i don't what happened just showing in Printdialogbox bet printing zero;